# If $A, G, H$ ∈ $M_n$ be positive definite , $GAG = HAH$ then $G = H$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

Let $A, G, H$ ∈ $M_n$ be positive definite and suppose that $GAG = HAH$.

Why does  $G = H$?

It is well known that the square root of a positive definite matrix is unique (see [Square root of Positive Definite Matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349721/square-root-of-positive-definite-matrix)), but this only solves the case $A=\rm{id}$. Does the general case also follow from this?

Comment: Take $A = [1, 0; 0, 1]$, $G = [1, 0; 0, 1]$, and $H = [-1, 0; 0, -1]$. $GAG = HAH$ holds, but $G = -H$!

Comment: @m0_as: $H$ is not positive definite.

Comment: @PhoemueX you are right. I made a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general case also follows from the uniqueness of square roots as follows:

If we multiply your assumption by $A^{1/2}$ from left and right, we get
$$
(A^{1/2} G A^{1/2} )(A^{1/2}  G A^{1/2} ) = (A^{1/2}  H A^{1/2} ) (A^{1/2}  H A^{1/2} ).
$$

Since both $A^{1/2} G A^{1/2} $ and $A^{1/2}  H A^{1/2} $ are positive definite (why?), uniqueness of square roots shows that they are identical. By multiplying with $A^{-1/2} $ from the left and right, we get $G=H$ as desired.