# How to calculate the negative half power of a matrix

Tags: matrices

I have a square matrix called A. How can I find $A ^ {-1/2}$. Should I compute $a_{ij} ^ {-1/2}$ for all of its elements?

Thanks

Comment: What properties has $A$? Not all matrices have a square root and when it has one there is often non-uniqueness, one has to ask for properties satisfied by the square root. Typically, if $A$ is [symmetric definite positive](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349721/square-root-of-positive-definite-matrix), $A$ has a unique positive definite square root.

Comment: Try that construction for a 2-by-2 example and see if $(A^{-1/2})^2=A^{-1}$. If it doesn't, then that's not $A^{-1/2}$.

Answer (score 6):

$A=SDS^{−1}$, and $A^k=SD^kS^{−1}$ where D is the diagonal matrix composed from eigenvalues, S is the matrix of eigenvectors, and $S^{−1}$ is the inverse of S.

So the first step is to find the eigenvalues, and then find the corresponding eigenvectors.
Then use $A^{1/2}=SD^{1/2}S^{-1}$, and finally find the inverse $A^{-1/2}=(A^{1/2})^{-1}$

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you will need to **pick a branch** of the square root function over the field of which the elements of your matrix belong. Once you have done that,

1. **If $A$ is diagonalizable** you can do as @Annalise writes.
2. **If $A$ is orthogonally diagonalizable** you can do as @Junning Li writes.

However for example if $A$ is not diagonalizable, then it can maybe still be put on some canonical form:

$$A = TCT^{-1}$$

Where $C$ can be block-diagonal matrix. In this case we can do approximate square root by trying some power series expansion on the diagonal blocks of $C$. However this is **not guaranteed** to make any sense. It will depend a lot on application.

Answer (score 1):

It exists only if $A$ is invertible, i.e. $A^{-1}$ exists. Now this matrix have to [follow certain properties , then a square root can be computed.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix)

You always have the EVD at hand. Break the matrix $A^{-1}=U\cdot \Sigma\cdot U^t$ Where $U$ is a unitary matrix.Check that $$(U\cdot \Sigma^{1/2}\cdot U^t)^2=U\cdot \Sigma^{1/2}\cdot U^t\cdot U\cdot \Sigma^{1/2}\cdot U^t=A^{-1}$$
And $[\Sigma^k]_{ii}=[\Sigma_{ii}^k]$

Answer (score 1):

Eigen-decomposition: $A = U * \Lambda * U^t$.

$A^{-1/2} = U * \Lambda^{-1/2} * U^t$.

This method is not a very good for numerical computation.