# What is the proof of the fact "a positive definite matrix has a unique positive definite square root"?

Tags: matrices, proof-verification, roots, positive-definite

Could someone write the proof of this thing with a reference?

Comment: this post asking about uniqueness whereas im looking for a proof for its existence

Comment: Take an eigenbasis for the matrix, and write down how the square root matrix must act on the basis. You’ll see there is only one possible answer.

Answer (score 0):

This almost follows from the answer to which @lhf was referring above: [Square root of Positive Definite Matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349721/square-root-of-positive-definite-matrix).
Let's go:

$A$ positive definite $\Rightarrow \; \exists\, U $ unitary, $D$ diagonal **with positive entries** s.t. $A=UDU^{\ast}$.

Define a diagonal matrix $\sqrt{D}$ by taking positive square roots of the diagonal entries of $D$. 
Then, define $B:= U \sqrt{D}U^\ast$.

This $B$ will be the square root of $A$. To prove that, first compute the following: 
$$
B^2 = B\cdot B = ... = A\;.
$$
**Almost trivial hint:** Use the unitary property of $U$.

It remains to show that that $B$ is as well positive definite. This follows by our construction: Could $\sqrt{D}$ have non-positive values if $A$ is positive definite? If no, this implies that $B$ is positive definite.

Comment: $B$ is trivially PD if you know that $A$ is positive definite $\iff$ $\exists U$ unitary etc.

Comment: Of course. Strictly speaking I would not say **trivial** though, since this is technically not a tautology.
OP seems to be an undergrad student or not a mathematician (yet), so I tried to stress that the proof is not over once you prove $B^2=A$. These things are vital if one is on the beginning of a mathematical career.

Comment: Oh I totally agree with you, I just added the comment for the OP in case he had trouble with the last part.